# AS3 - Loading Image Coordinates from URL

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, url, air

I am developing an Android App in Air for Android using Flash Pro CC & I am tired of pushing updates all the time to change a spawn location for an image that needs to move every few days to a specific location. I won't know the location until just minutes before the update needs to be pushed & it would be much faster to simply have the app load the spawn coordinates for the image upon launch from my website in a .txt file. I would need something where I just type the X and Y coordinates in a file & then the information is loaded and AS3 spawns the image at those coordinates. If no coordinates are available in the text file (as 5 days of the week there won't be), I need a different image to be displayed wherever I place it. I will probably just have a separate frame for that though.

Any help is greatly appreciated & I'd prefer it if the image can be used in a motion tween but if not then I will work something out.

NOTE: I am new to AS3 coding but I have Flash itself figured out for animating with the timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the finished code here. loadURL is the Document Class loaded by Flash. Everything works great!

```
package  {
    // IMPORTS EVENTS USED
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.UncaughtErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    // DECLARES VARIABLES
    public class loadURL extends MovieClip {
        public var Xurl:String = "URL GOES HERE";
        public var Yurl:String = "URL GOES HERE";
        public var URLloaderX:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        public var URLloaderY:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        public var marker:Marker = new Marker();
        public var gone:Gone = new Gone();
        public var connectionerr:ConnectionErr = new ConnectionErr();

        // CODE EXECUTED UPON LAUNCH
        public function loadURL() {
            // constructor code
            trace("Loaded");
            URLloaderX.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandlerX);
            URLloaderX.load(new URLRequest(Xurl));
            URLloaderY.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandlerY);
            URLloaderY.load(new URLRequest(Yurl));
            loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);
        }
function completeHandlerX(event:Event):void
    {
        if(URLloaderX.data == null||URLloaderX.data==(""))
            {addChild(gone)}
        else{addChild(marker);marker.x = (URLloaderX.data)}
    }
function completeHandlerY(event:Event):void
    {
        if(URLloaderY.data == null||URLloaderY.data==("")){}
            marker.y = (URLloaderY.data)
    }

private function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void //Checks for no internet connection

    {
        e.preventDefault(); //leave this

// RESULT OF NO INTERNET HERE
        addChild(connectionerr);
    }   
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`URLRequest`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) and [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) for retrieving the data. For spawning the image at a specific location, consider just moving it instead; Any object on stage is a [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html), and DisplayObjects have properties `x` and `y`. For swapping out the images, look at [`DisplayObjectContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html), specifically the functions [`DisplayObjectContainer.addChild(child:DisplayObject)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()) and [`DisplayObjectContainer.removeChild(child:DisplayObject)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChild()). I have provided links to the documentation for each of the relevant functions.

If the update is on a daily basis, have a look at the [`Date`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) class too - that will allow you to find out what date it is and whether you need to make an url request to load the textfile to display the image.

If you have any specific questions regarding the use of these classes, I think it's best if you make a new question with a link back to this one for context. You're good with English, not so good with AS3 (as you say), so I could explain the relevant bits where needed, but it would be a long and complex story if I were to explain this entire functionality in one go. ... I think you'll find that these class names will make googling easier too.

---

I expect that you'll have to use an `URLLoader` with an `URLRequest` to load the textfile, then depending on the results, display the image by adding it to stage via `addChild` if it's not there yet, and then setting its `x` and `y` values. You'll have to use the `Date` class to check whether you need to make a new request every time the user starts the application or does some specific action.